# Two autocomplete variables, second one should depend on first one - Simple JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this question is posted before, but didn't find it in javascript/jquery.

So I have two inputs, first one is a city, and second one is a part of that specific city that we chose in first input:

```js
$(function() {
  var city = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"];
  $("#city").autocomplete({
    source: city
  });
  var addressforoption1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];

  var addressforoption2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"];

  var addressforoption3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];

  var addressforoption4 = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"];

  var answer = document.querySelector('#city').value;//tried changing this to innerText or innerHTML still the same
  if (answer = "option1") {
    address = addressforoption1
  }
  if (answer = "option2") {
    address = addressforoption2
  }
  if (answer = "option3") {
    address = addressforoption3
  }
  if (answer = "option4") {
    address = addressforoption4
  }
  $("#location").autocomplete({
    source: address
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="city">➡ City<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" required name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city name here">
<hr>
<label for="location">➡ Location<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" required name="location" id="location" placeholder="City location">
```

**Problem**: First autocomplete works with charm, and you can pick any city you want, exactly like it should. But second autocomplete is always last one - option 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use double equal sign operator (`==`) for comparison and then change your code to something like this

```js
$(function() {
  var city = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"];
  var addressforoption1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];
  var addressforoption2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"];
  var addressforoption3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];
  var addressforoption4 = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"];

  $("#city").autocomplete({
    source: city,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var answer = ui.item.value;

      if (answer == "option1") {
        address = addressforoption1
      } else if (answer == "option2") {
        address = addressforoption2
      } else if (answer == "option3") {
        address = addressforoption3
      } else if (answer == "option4") {
        address = addressforoption4
      } else {
        address = []
      }

      $("#location").autocomplete('option', 'source', address);
    }
  });

  $("#location").autocomplete({
    source: []
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="city">➡ City<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" required name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city name here">
<hr>
<label for="location">➡ Location<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" required name="location" id="location" placeholder="City location">
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `select` and `change` methods to your code.

`select` -
You can use the `select` property in autocomplete to pass along the selected value, here I just call the function `setAddressValue` that basically does the same as what you did before.

`change` -
select only handles when the user actually selects the value from the autocomplete-list. if I manually enter `option1` and then try, nothing is going to happen. So therefore, I added the `change` method which basically checks whenever a user is leaving the input field.

```js
$(function() {
  const city = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"];
  $("#city").autocomplete({
    source: city,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      setAddressValue(ui.item.value);
    }
  }).change(function() {
    setAddressValue(this.value);
  });


  const setAddressValue = (answer) => {
    let address = [];
    if (answer === "option1") address = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];
    else if (answer === "option2") address = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"];
    else if (answer === "option3") address = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"];
    else if (answer === "option4") address = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"];
    else adress

    $("#location").autocomplete({
      source: address
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="city">➡ City<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" required name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city name here">
<hr>
<label for="location">➡ Location<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" required name="location" id="location" placeholder="City location">
```

---

Notes: `if(answer = "option1")` will assign `option1` to `answer`. Essentially what you did was to check if `answer` was a truthy value, and a string is a truthy value. *So therefore all if-cases were true.*, And that's why it always showed the last one, it passed through them all. You need to do `==` or `===` for comparisons.

Don't use `var`. Use `const` for variables that you wont reassign, and `let` for variables you want to re-assign a value to.